# Spring RESTful Web Service in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, maven

I am trying to run the Spring Guides project “*Building a RESTful Web Service*” in Netbeans 8.1.

The project builds successfully but when I run the project I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
(default-cli) on project gs-rest-service: Command execution failed.
Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

What does "Command execution failed" mean, and what should I do about it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips. The question as posted doesn't contain a "question", but perhaps you meant one of these: "What does this error mean?" or "What should I do when I see this error?"